# Replace all occurrences of an element in a list with the index of its first occurrence, Python

Tags: python, list

Say I have this lovely list here:

```
my_list = ["Andy", "Ben", "Andy", "Ben", "Carol", "Ben"]
```

I want to replace each element with the order it appears in (so "Andy" -> 1, "Ben" -> 2, "Carol"-> 3). The list I want to get back is this:

```
ordered_list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```

This can be done with an integer variable as a counter and a dictionary where I store the order in which each element of my list appears. However that feels crude and not Pythonic.

What would be a sleek one-liner that uses list comprehension to accomplish my task for me? Is there one out there or is my case too niche?

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Sleek one-liners” usually aren’t the thing you should be going for. Forcing solutions to be one-liners often yields to a process similar to [code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) where readability really suffers. Instead, you should attempt to produce readable code. In Python, this can often lead to one-liners but it certainly isn’t a requirement nor a guarantee.

In this case, we can almost use a one-liner. The solution I’m a using here uses `dict.setdefault` to retrieve and set a dictionary value at the same time. That way, as we loop through the original list, we can get the previously stored index from it or update the dictionary with the new index:

```
my_list = ["Andy", "Ben", "Andy", "Ben", "Carol", "Ben"]

indexes = {}
order_list = [indexes.setdefault(x, len(indexes) + 1) for x in my_list]

print(order_list) # [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you! I'm trying to get comfortable with list comprehension so I'm taking every opportunity to use it that I can. That being said, I'll definitely watch out to make sure my code stays readable and simple.